# Cocos Creator & VSCode breakpoint error in Mac

Tags: typescript, cocoscreator

I trying install cocos Creator & Vscode in Mac OS pc. and I try debug with chrome.

I install plugin Chrome Extiontion Developer. and Cocos Debug.

And I set launch.json like this.

And I Also give accesss disk permission to cocosdashboard , VsCode, Google Chrome.

```
{
    "version": "1.4.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Creator Debug: Launch Chrome",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:7456",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "userDataDir": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/chrome",
            "diagnosticLogging": false,
            "pathMapping": {
                "/preview-scripts/assets": "${workspaceFolder}/temp/quick-scripts/dst/assets",
                "/": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }    
        }
    ]
}
```

And I do also this 5 things.

[image]

I can use debug mode with vsCode but breakPoint is not work.

Please Help. I trying 2~3 days for fix it.

install plugin Chrome Extiontion Developer. and Cocos Debug.

set launch.json

try debug typescript, javascript and remake project. and test in empty project.

add CompilerOptions "sourceMap":true, in tsconfig.json

expecting

- Maybe VSCode can't find  scripts in assets folder.